# Problema al conectarme a una base de datos mysql alojado a un servidor con C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2017

### Problema C# y Mysql

Mi problema es que mi aplicación creada en c# con el IDE Visual Studio 2017 me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

> unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

Este problema surgió desde que pase mi base de datos local a un servidor web, ya probé en el Cpanel del sitio web la opción de remote access pero simplemente no me conecta.

Mi cadena de conexión es la siguiente:

```
servidor = "miServidor"; 
baseDatos = "miBaseDatos"; 
usuario = "miUsuario";
password = "miContraseña"; 
string cadenaConeccion; 
cadenaConeccion = "SERVER=" + servidor + ";" + "DATABASE=" + baseDatos + ";" 
                  + "UID=" + usuario + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
coneccion = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConeccion);
```

Ya traté conectarme utilizando workbench y tampoco funciona, deshabilite el firewall de windows y no funciona, estoy tratando de conectarme desde la pc donde estoy corriendo el cpanel no sé si eso tenga algo que ver.

¿Alguna sugerencia de cuál puede ser mi problema?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, puedes mostrarnos la cadena de conexión sobre la que estás trabajando? Tal vez no la tengas bien definida y estés apuntando a un sitio erróneo

Comment: Además de lo que comenta @SergioParraGuerra, pudiera ser de interés que probaras a conectarte con un cliente de MySQL (como MySQL Workbench por ejemplo) y ver si puedes conectarte con los datos de conexión de los que dispones.

Comment: Hola, puedes editar tu pregunta y poner el contenido de tu comentario en ella? Así se verá más claro. Gracias

Comment: Ya lo hice lo siento soy nuevo aquí .

Comment: Has habilitado las conexiones remotas en la bbdd? Creo que te hace falta indicar el puerto sobre el que conectarte. Un ejemplo de cadena de conexión puede ser: Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

Comment: El que desde el workbench tampoco te puedas conectar indica que el problema no está en como te conectas, no obstante el formato que estás utilizando para la cadena de conexión no es el soportado, debiera ser `Pwd` en lugar de `Password`. Suele ser muy práctico revisar las cadenas de conexión para cada proveedor en este [link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/).

Comment: Ya lo intenté cambiando a pwd y agregando el puerto y sigue sin funcionar, mi servidor de Hosting es ecowebhosting.co.uk.

Comment: Hay veces que estos hosting tiene una lista blanca, que permite habilitar las ip que tendran conexion con tu maquina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Al parecer era error de la página de hosting, cambié de proveedor y me funcionó correctamente.**

Answer (score 1):

prueba a dar permisos a tu usuario de la siguiente forma desde tu mySQL

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Luego haz un bind a todas las direcciones comentando la línea siguiente en `my.cnf`

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

y reiniciar el servicio mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

Comment: Muchas gracias trate pero lamentablemente no funcionó, estoy pensando en que tal vez sea el hosting, tratarè de contratar Go Daddy espero que con ese si sirva.